# Is there something fishy on Kaspersky Internet Security or I am missing something?

Tags: virus, antivirus, antimalware, anti-exploitation

Whenever I turn on my computer, a notification pops up - **You need to restart you PC (I have added screenshot)**. I did, but it keeps coming. So went to notification center and saw which application is causing this, it was my antivirus - **Kaspersky Internet Security**. So I opened the application and there was no restart like notification/message/advice or anything.

One other thing - nowadays when I turn on my PC another mysterious thing happens, it says my security is turned off, although when I click there - it says both are running and even before clicking there, the **Kaspersky Internet Security** icon is green and keeps flashing there(normally happens when it is functional). I have even checked it on task manager.

Screenshot: *Both notification is visible there*

[image]

*N.B.:* I have the latest version of Windows too

[image: win10 updated fully]

Checked event-log, searched with different key-words too.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Checked *Windows Defender* too

[image]

Can anyone tell me what is happening?

What should I do?

Reboot and reboot...

[image]

Comment: A malware infection is possible here, although maybe not what has actually happened.

Comment: I have scanned whole PC, internet security and windows both are legit, now what can I do ?

Comment: You could possibly scan your PC with another AV. You could try and scan your PC using the ESET AV https://www.eset.com/uk/home/free-trial/ , i'm purely recommending it  as it wont overlap with your current AV.

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad When you say you've scanned the computer, do you mean you scanned it *with Kapersky?*  Not meaning to be a fearmonger, but if Kapersky is the program behaving oddly, its results may not be trustworthy.

Comment: Yes, I scanned with Kaspersky, I had nothing else

Comment: Anything about it in event viewer logs?

Comment: no, nothing in the event viewer log, I have checked and added ss in question

Comment: windows Defender hates all AVs. navigate to "windows defender security center" and check if there are any "actions required" there .

Comment: checked that too, please see

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this on Windows 10 in combination with Kaspersky 11.

Other security software may interfere with the functionality and can cause this to happen or updates to actually be up to date but not show so.

A complete reinstall of Kaspersky  usually fixes the problem because at reinstall it also rebuilds the necessary security settings that may otherwise cause interference.

Also, make sure licensing is fine, since if license expires certain functionalities will be suspended.

The core problem though is most likely to be a Windows update. Many times I found them to cause security programs including Kas not to work anymore after update. Having an additional security program like the ones for document encryption only increases the incompatibility of windows updates with everything else security related.

Comment: I still have 67 days of my licence

Comment: I can't install my **Kaspersky Internet Security** more than 5 times a year, that is not something related but surely funny- that's why shared

Comment: I have updated the answer since the actual core problem is from something else.

Comment: I have the latest version but it still occurs

Comment: Having latest version of all updates can actually cause the problems. You should exclude updates that are known to break various security things. Unfortunately, this is not too easy to determine. In W10 an update can breaks things and can take quite a while for it to get fixed with another. during that interval, you either have to remove the bad update or not install it at all.